# Filtering with LIKE operator with case-sensitivity

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to do an API call using the LIKE operator however its not returning data case sensitive. How would I go about doing this. So far I have:

```
        queryEvent.query = queryEvent.combo.displayField + " like " + "'%" + query + "%'";
```

And the filter it generates: filter=name%20like%20%27%25Test%25%27

Comment: This looks like a SQL query? If so, what is the SQL engine? In postgres you use `ilike` for case insensitivity. Also as an aside: if you're not already, it would be good to use some method of escaping your query text to prevent an injection attack

Answer (score 0):

The content that is generated is using URL Encoding. You need to decode this to get the actual value. Use any standard URL decoder library to do the same.

Or use the following program

```
public String decodeURL (String url){

try {
    String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return result;
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // not going to happen - value came from JDK's own StandardCharsets
}
   return url;
}
```